# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle

when i was trying to read data from Oracle database using the following code i was getting exception

```
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from food");
```

But this table is actually exist in my database when i use this command directly in the command prompt its working fine.And also for one table among the tables in database this code is working fine ,but for other table names its not working properly.So someone please explain why this is happening.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:852)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1477)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:392)
    at connecttooracle.ConnectOracle.main(ConnectOracle.java:67)
```

I am accessing data from food table by Toad . THen why am I getting this error in java ?

My full code is :

```
public class ConnectOracle {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; //

  String serverName = "10.11.201.84";
  String portNumber = "1521";
  String db = "XE";
  String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":"
    + db; // connectOracle is the data
  // source name
  String user = "ORAP"; // username of oracle database
  String pwd = "ORAP"; // password of oracle database
  Connection con = null;
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

  try {
   Class.forName(driver);// for loading the jdbc driver

   System.out.println("JDBC Driver loaded");

   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);// for
                // establishing
   // connection
   // with database
   Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
   System.out.println("Listening :8888");

   while (true) {
    try {

     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     System.out.println("Connection Created");
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
       socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
       socket.getOutputStream());
     System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
     // System.out.println("message: " +
     // dataInputStream.readUTF());

     ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from food");
     while(res.next()){
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: if table is exist on your db, then check your db connection in your app

Comment: Try to add your database schema before your table `food`.

Comment: How can I  add database schema  ?

Comment: have you check your db connection info ?! maybe you have wrong info to connect or you have multiple connections, for example one connection to oracle and another connection to mysql !

Comment: How can I check that ?

Comment: The given error message in Spring is ridiculous. There could be variety of reason this can happen. It can be mismatch between entity class and actual DB columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your table is located under schema A:

```
select * from A.food
```

**EDIT**

If you can login via TOAD with user ORAP and execute the same query (select * from food) then you definitely have the table in ORAP schema. I see no reason for "select * from ORAP.food" to fail.

Comment: I have tried it . ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from XE.food"); But I am getting the same error .

Comment: XE is your database name. use "ORAP.food"

Comment: What are the problems ?

Comment: Your table is probably located under a different schema. You said you can login with TOAD, so log in and see your table's schema then change the query accordingly.

or try this query on TOAD to see schema name if you have the privilage :
select owner from all_tables where table_name='food'

Comment: I have tried this query . select owner from all_tables where table_name='food' .But do not get anything .

Comment: Do you login to toad with ORAP user or another one?

Comment: I have login with ORAP user in Toad.

Comment: But the query select * from ORAP.food gives me the same error both in java and toad .

Comment: Then I suspect food is not the table name but a synonym which points to a table in another schema. Can you run this: "select * from all_synonyms where table_name='food'". If it returns any result, use "OWNER.TABLE_NAME" in your query

Comment: What was the answer to the problem? What is the solution?

Comment: All I did is rerun the liquibase script in upper case table name!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the possible solutions are:

> You can create connection in the database by the schema under which database is located.

***For example:*** My original database has admin **SYSTEM** and then I created an user **Toad** and under this Toad schema I have created the table **Food**.

So I will create connection to the database by:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "Toad", "PasswordOfToad");
```

Then the query `ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Food");` will work fine.

> Alternatively you could specify the table by **SchemaName.DatabaseName**, which in this case is *Toad* and *Food* respectively.

So the query would look like:

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Toad.Food");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and something like this works for me:

```
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from \"food\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and the solution was to execute:

```
grant all on <schema>.<table> to <user>;
grant all on <schema>.<sequence> to <user>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00942_table_or_view_does_not_exist.htm). There are all reasons ans solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this CAUSE,u found this exception.
You tried to execute a SQL statement that references a table or view that either does not exist, that you do not have access to, or that belongs to another schema and you didn't reference the table by the schema name.

Comment: I have checked all this but nothing happen .

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem so i can give the solution.

Comment: use your scemaName.tableName in query

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- First login to TOAD using same username and password. If it gives error then your credentials are wrong
- If you are able to login successfully then try this query: `SELECT table_name, owner, tablespace_name FROM all_tables;`
- You can see your table name is present or not using above query

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue,
Resolution is:

1. Open the hibernate.cfg.xml file
2. Add your POJO class using

Also check,
true
update

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem:

Open the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file

> Check the mapping properly
>
> `<mapping class="com.xyz.abc.java"/>`

Also make sure below line:

> `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem executing:

```
grant all on <schema>.<table> to <user>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention Schema.table For Example Schema name=xyz then the query would be:select * from xyz.food Try this, this will work

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem but resolved using grant privilege,

when i run standalone application using the following query their is no error:

```
String sql = "select * from SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

---

But when i run through a web-based application, As each user has different roles with permissions. If user doesn't have particular SELECT permission then it leads to the ERROR.

> For TABLES if the USER_ROLE does not have an select permission. Then leads to the following error as `ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist`:

[**GRANT (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) - ADD SELECT privilege for tables:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME TO "USER_ROLE";
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME TO "USER_ROLE";
GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME TO "USER_ROLE";
```

```log
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:873)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1491)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
```

> For Stored procedure if the USER_ROLE  does not have an execute permission. Then leads to the following error as `Internal Error: Inconsistent catalog view`

ADD [EXECUTE privilege for Stored Procedure/Functions](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/35142/):

```sql
GRANT DEBUG ON SCHEMA_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME TO "USER_ROLE";
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME TO "USER_ROLE";
```

```log
java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Inconsistent catalog view
at oracle.sql.StructDescriptor.initMetaData1_9_0(StructDescriptor.java:1420)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add schema in @Table annotation on Entity class.

> @Table(name = "tableName", schema = "schemaName")

Answer (score 0):

Check the entity class fields and actual table columns matches in number and name. This was the case in my case. Also in other  environment, I had to rerun the liquibase script in uppercase table name. Somehow the same issue didn't happen in another environment regards to the case of table name.